# OpenJPA - ArgumentException: JDBC driver or data source class name

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, openjpa

I'm creating an OpenJPA application with maven.
The application starts, but if I try to access a database-entity, I get the following exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 - <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: The persistence provider is attempting to use properties in the persistence.xml file to resolve the data source. A Java Database onnectivity (JDBC) driver or data source class name must be specified in the openjpa.ConnectionDriverName or javax.persistence.jdbc.driver property. The following properties are available in the configuration: "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl@442ce698".
```

The persistence.xml is located in META-INF and is under control by Netbeans 8.
The ConnectionDriverName is set as the following:

```
<property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"/>
```

My src\main\java\META-INF\persistence.xml (class-tags reduced and database-settings changed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <class>com.example.test.my.entities.User</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema"/>
      <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>
      <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.MySQLDictionary"/>
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"/>
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrettyPrint=true, PrettyPrintLineLength=80, PrintParameters=true"/>
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionProperties" value="DriverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver,
             Url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?autoReconnect=true,
             Username=usr,
             Password=pwd,
             MaxWait=60000,
             TestOnBorrow=true,
             validationQuery=select 1"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I'm using Tomcat 8 (same result for Tomcat 7 or Tomee).

Comment: Edit the question and add the persistence.xml file.

Comment: Post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by switching to eclipse, because it seems like netbeans having some problems with the persistence.xml.
In eclipse I had to use the following m2e-connector:
https://github.com/hwellmann/m2eclipse-extras/raw/master/p2/ (eclipse software repository url)